# WindowManager crash on Android OS 6 specific devices

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am using a service to create a facebook messenger style chatHead. My code works fine for devices having android OS till 6(Marshmallow). But on M device the code crashes with a runtime exception on windowManager.addView()

The code is as follow:

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
callHead = new ImageView(this);
callHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flow_flat);
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;     
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
params.x = 0;
params.y = 100;
params.height = 120; // given it a fixed height in case of large image
params.width = 120;
windowManager.addView(callHead, params);
```

the crash I am receiving is

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$InvalidDisplayException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@b40f577 -- the specified window type is not valid
```

Comment: The docs says  addview(params) **Throws WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException if the window is on a secondary Display and the specified display can't be found (see Presentation).** and here's the docs for presentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html. Although i haven't tried this check the docs and see if you can figure out whats wrong

Comment: it require permission to draw over another app from marshmallow.and we check it by going to app and permission in settings.i dnt knw about the code but you should check about the marshmallow permission for that.

Comment: Yes it requires permission. check this http://qiita.com/chibatching/items/add5e50921c2da5ee1c7 translate to english

Comment: @AvinashRanjan i tried it myself and posted the same check if that works for oyu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at http://qiita.com/chibatching/items/add5e50921c2da5ee1c7 and trying out myself

Check if your code runs on Marshmallow and above. If yes check if the app has a permission to draw overlay. If not direct the user to the settings. In onActivityResult you can call displayOverdraw if user has granted permission. If the user has granted permission previously there is no need to display settings screen again.

```
 public void checkdrawPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            } else {
                 // display over lay from service
            }
        }else
        {
             // display over lay from service
        }
    }
```

onActivityResult callback

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    // You have permission
                    // display over lay from service
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The draw overlay in Service

```
public void displayOverdraw() {

    ImageView callHead = new ImageView(this);
    callHead.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(callHead, params);
}
```

Note: for the sake of testing i tried this in activity. In service you cannot call startActivityForResult

Comment: This is the way to do it! But I can't increase the sdkVersion to 23(due to other issues) , which is the version to in which Settings.canDrawOverlays(Context context) is introduced.

Comment: @Avijeet these permissions are required only on 23 and above. Before that you don't need them

Comment: @Avijeet and note that startActivityforresult will not work in Service. for the sake of testing i tried this in activity. But it should be service.

Comment: superb Sir @Raghunandan